Kubernetes FlinkSessionJob launching multiple instance of same Job
I am using Kubernetes operator for flink jobs. After recent migration to Java 17 and flink 18. The FlinkSessionJob is now launching multiple instances of the same job(there is 2 job in the screenshot).
Yaml for one job looks like below. Jar file runs on local docker based setup. SO I believe this has to be with the Kubernetes Operator reconciliation process or some config which is not right. I looked for different things nothing helped. Any help is appreciated thanks.
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkSessionJob
metadata:
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "3"
    helm.sh/hook-weight: "3"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"flink.apache.org/v1beta1","kind":"FlinkSessionJob","metadata":{"annotations":{"argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave":"3","helm.sh/hook-weight":"3"},"labels":{"argocd.argoproj.io/instance":"flink-avalanche-analytics"},"name":"segment-data","namespace":"namespace"},"spec":{"deploymentName":"deploymentName","job":{"args":[],"entryClass":"com.entryClass","jarURI":"s3://uri/jar-files/avalanche/avalanche-1.42-SNAPSHOT.jar","parallelism":1,"state":"running","upgradeMode":"savepoint"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-04-16T01:27:11Z"
  finalizers:
  - flinksessionjobs.flink.apache.org/finalizer
  generation: 1
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: flink-avalanche-analytics
    target.session: flink-avalanche-analytics
  name: name
  namespace: namespace
  resourceVersion: "385932768"
  uid: 6b968e8d-5bc5-4f46-9258-9eb6d11d6c55
spec:
  deploymentName: deploymentName
  job:
    args:
   
    entryClass: com.entryClass
    jarURI: s3://uri/avalanche-1.42-SNAPSHOT.jar
    parallelism: 1
    state: running
    upgradeMode: savepoint
status:
  error: '{"type":"org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.exception.ReconciliationException","message":"org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException:
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException","additionalMetadata":{},"throwableList":[{"type":"org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException","message":"java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException","additionalMetadata":{}},{"type":"java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException","additionalMetadata":{}}]}'
  jobStatus:
    checkpointInfo:
      lastPeriodicCheckpointTimestamp: 0
    jobId: 37145346a059268dbba9092d8e3ae1e3
    jobName: avalanche-1.42-kinesis-ingest-segment-shared-um16362-DEV_LANDING_STREAMING-TEST
    savepointInfo:
      lastPeriodicSavepointTimestamp: 0
      savepointHistory: []
    startTime: "1713231819705"
    state: RUNNING
    updateTime: "1713244480535"
  lifecycleState: STABLE
  observedGeneration: 1
  reconciliationStatus:
    lastReconciledSpec: '{"spec":{"job":{"jarURI":"s3://s3-flink-infra-dev/jar-files/avalanche/avalanche-1.42-SNAPSHOT.jar","parallelism":1,"entryClass":"com.adaptavist.bsp.Avalanche","args":[],"state":"running","savepointTriggerNonce":null,"initialSavepointPath":null,"checkpointTriggerNonce":null,"upgradeMode":"stateless","allowNonRestoredState":null,"savepointRedeployNonce":null},"restartNonce":null,"flinkConfiguration":null,"deploymentName":"flink-avalanche-analytics"},"resource_metadata":{"apiVersion":"flink.apache.org/v1beta1","metadata":{"generation":1},"firstDeployment":true}}'
    lastStableSpec: '{"spec":{"job":{"jarURI":"s3://uri/jar-files/avalanche/avalanche-1.42-SNAPSHOT.jar","parallelism":1,"entryClass":"com.adaptavist.bsp.Avalanche","args":[],"state":"running","savepointTriggerNonce":null,"initialSavepointPath":null,"checkpointTriggerNonce":null,"upgradeMode":"stateless","allowNonRestoredState":null,"savepointRedeployNonce":null},"restartNonce":null,"flinkConfiguration":null,"deploymentName":"deploymentName"},"resource_metadata":{"apiVersion":"flink.apache.org/v1beta1","metadata":{"generation":1},"firstDeployment":true}}'
    reconciliationTimestamp: 1713231688057
    state: DEPLOYED


I fixed it.  For anyone in future, the culprit was the config Kubernetes.operator.observer.progress-check.interval. The default time to check was 5 sec. however, this was too low for any specific changes. The observer misunderstands the state as failed/not started and launches another instance. I set it to 15 sec and it stabilized it
